# Compare strings in array after split in Java

Tags: java

I have a string that I use split function on it in order to split it to the different parts.
Then I want to check if the array contain a certain value, I tried using a for loop and also converting the array to a List and using the contain options but I get the same result - the text is not in the array.

P.S.
I edited the code to show a better example.

```
String categories = "C1-C-D-A-1-В";
String[] cat = categories.split("-");
String catCode = "B";

//always return false
if (Arrays.asList(cat).contains(catCode))
{
//do somthing
}

for (int idxCat = 0; idxCat < cat.length; idxCat++) {
    //always return false
    if ((cat[idxCat]).equals(catCode))
    {
       //do somthing
       break;
     }
}
```

Comment: `Code` is String object or some custom obejct, please update question accordingly. This is what I am referring `Arrays.asList(cat).contains(Code)`.

Comment: I am not sure exactly what you are asking. Are you trying to find a certain value (ex. "dog") in your array of strings?

Comment: Please post the value of `Code` (you shouldn't capitalize variable names) and at least partial content of `categories`.

Comment: Did you try `equalsIgnoreCase()`, may be the strings are not in same case?

Comment: Give an example of a string that's in `categories`, and what the `Code`/`licenseCode` is. I also recommend checking what's actually in your `cat` array by using `System.out.println(Arrays.toString(cat))` right after the split.

Comment: Works just fine for me, if the `Code` value is in the original `categories`. Watch spaces and upper/lowercase distinctions.

Comment: I found out what the problem is, apparently instead of a Latin B, there was a Cyrillic B (in the naked eye it's look the same, using debugger I found the difference)
Thanks for all the help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I made a quick demo of what it seems you are asking.

If you are trying to see if any of the strings in your array contain a certain value:

```
public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] strings = new String[] {"bob", "joe", "me"};

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
    {
      if (strings[i].contains("bob"))//doing "b" will also find "bob"
      {
        System.out.println("Found it!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The console output is: Found it!

I would suggest trying to use equalsIgnoreCase() as mentioned in the comments. You may also want to show the values in your array:

```
import java.util.Arrays;

public class HelloWorld
{
  public static void main(String[] args)
  {
    String[] strings = new String[] {"bob", "joe", "me"};

    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(strings));

    for (int i = 0; i < strings.length; i++)
    {
      if (strings[i].contains("bob"))
      {
        System.out.println("Found it!");
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Output:

> [bob, joe, me]
>
> Found it!

This can help you to figure out if the values in the strings in  your array are actually the values that you think they are.